# how to give where condition in a case statement for each case while joining another table

Tags: sql, hive, case

I want join t.archer_fact_metrics_results table with b.lkp_nonpercentagekri table and derive a column derived_january. when t,January value is between those threshold values assign b.colour_indicator 's corresponding value of b.proxy_percentage_value to
derived_january else keep t.january value as is to derived_january column

```
 select
        (case 
        when (Format = 'Monetary Amount' or Format = 'Number')
        then case when (t.January >= green_threshold_min and t.January <=green_threshold_max) then b.proxy_percentage_value and b.colour_indicator='Green' 
            when (t.January >= amber_threshold_min and t.January <= amber_threshold_max) then b.proxy_percentage_value  and b.colour_indicator = 'Amber'
            when (t.January >= red_threshold_min and t.January <= red_threshold_max)then b.proxy_percentage_value and b.colour_indicator = 'Red' 
            else t.January end 
         end) as derived_january
    from kri.archer_fact_metrics_results t
    join kri.lkp_nonpercentagekri b on t.p2g_status = b.colour_indicator
```

getting error :SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableDoubleObjectInspector
cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector

input values

```
b.proxy_percentage_value    b.colour_indicator  t.January   t.green_threshold_min    t.green_threshold_max
55.0                         Green                  34            25                  60
34.0                         Amber                  25            20                  50
45.0                         Red                    25            35                  45
```

similar data for amber_threshold_min and amber_threshold_max and red_threshold_min and red_threshold_max

Expected:

```
derived_january
55.0
34.0
25
```

Comment: you can execut these SQL in database rather than program,maybe you can get more detail information about the error,I guess it is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your logic correctly, you need to use logic like `and b.colour_indicator = 'Red'`  inside case when. Because of that its throwing error.

You can ues below SQL -

```
 select
        (case 
        when (Format = 'Monetary Amount' or Format = 'Number')
        then case when (t.January >= green_threshold_min and t.January <=green_threshold_max and b.colour_indicator='Green' ) then b.proxy_percentage_value 
            when (t.January >= amber_threshold_min and t.January <= amber_threshold_max and b.colour_indicator = 'Amber') then b.proxy_percentage_value  
            when (t.January >= red_threshold_min and t.January <= red_threshold_max and b.colour_indicator = 'Red' )then b.proxy_percentage_value 
            else t.January end 
         end) as derived_january
    from kri.archer_fact_metrics_results t
    join kri.lkp_nonpercentagekri b on t.p2g_status = b.colour_indicator
```

Comment: I want to assgin b.proxy_percentage_value to derived_january where b.colour_indicator='Green' or 'Red' or 'Amber'

Comment: So is it like `(t.January >= green_threshold_min and t.January <=green_threshold_max and b.colour_indicator='Green' )` or `(t.January >= green_threshold_min and t.January <=green_threshold_max and b.colour_indicator in ('Amber','Red','Green' )`?